# JSF and PrimeFaces update

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm trying to update an outputLabel while run the process, but the value dont update. Hope someone can help;

```
        <p:graphicImage url="img/package.png" alt="a" width="20%" style="margin-left: 40%; margin-top: 3%;"/><br/>
        <div class="form">
            <h:form id="form">
                <h2>ANO</h2>
                <h:inputText value="#{processos.numeroAno}"/><br/>
                <h2>MESES</h2>
                <h:inputText value="#{processos.numeroMeses}"/><br/>
                <p:commandButton value="IMPORTAR" ajax="true" process="@form" actionListener="#{processos.processa}" update="form:mensagemErro" onstart="PF('statusDialog').show()" oncomplete="PF('statusDialog').hide()"></p:commandButton>
                <p:outputLabel value="#{processos.mensagemErro}" id="mensagemErro"/>
            </h:form>
        </div>

        <p:dialog widgetVar="statusDialog" modal="true" draggable="false" closable="false" resizable="false" showHeader="false">
            <p:graphicImage url="img/rubiks.gif" styleClass="" alt="a"/><br/>
        </p:dialog>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/geral.css"/>
```

.java

```
            files = pastaSap.listFiles();
        if (files.length == 1) {
            mensagemErro = "PASTA SAP OK";
            escreveLog("PASTA SAP OK", "GERAL");
        } else {
            mensagemErro = "PASTA SAP NÃO CONTÉM O NÚMERO NESCESSÁRIO DE ARQUIVOS (1)";
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: `update="mensagemErro"` should be `update="form:mensagemErro"`.

Comment: dosent work. i'll post the full xhtml

Comment: Does it enter that method at all?

Comment: Yes, the problem is that I want this message to update while the method run, and it just update when it end.

Comment: Oh, well you can't do that. Not like that, anyway. You should apply some asynchronous calls in order to do that.

Comment: So i cant do it with JSF and primefaces?

Comment: You can, maybe the easiest option is to use [primefaces push](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/notify.xhtml). You would update the message from javascript handler.